# Python HTTP 1.1 request from scratch

Tags: python, sockets, http

For my computer networks course we are required to code a client that implements HTTP1.1 HEAD, GET, POST and PUT commands. I'm having trouble however with putting a valid request together.

```
def HTTP_Request(command_type, uri, port):
    HTTP_command = f"{command_type} /HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost:{uri}\r\n\r\n"
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(uri), port))
    HTTP_command = HTTP_command.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(HTTP_command)
    response = client.recv(4096)
    print(response)
```

I'm calling the function with following parameters: HTTP_Request("GET", "www.google.com", 80), but I keep getting the 404 bad request status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> HTTP_command = f"{command_type} /HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost:{uri}\r\n\r\n"
> ```

This results in

```
 GET /HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost:www.google.com\r\n\r\n
```

But it should be slightly different - note the different amount of spaces at the marked positions:

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.google.com\r\n\r\n
     ^^^      ^^^
```